# Filter List based on permissions

Tags: list, permissions, security, groups

I am compiling a list for a company in sharepoint.

How can I set permissions on this based on department?

For example, if we have Sales, Accounts, Stores etc. How can this be set so any employee in Accounts can only add data and view data under the Accounts category but still part of the same list which a manager will be able to view all data from all departments in the same list?

Comment: I would look in to SharePoint Audiences it might be what you need https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Target-content-to-specific-audiences-33d84cb6-14ed-4e53-a426-74c38ea32293

Comment: I have created views on the list but cant see a way to assign permissions to each view. Would it be better using managed navigation and set permissions on each page? each page being a different department.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is add folder's to you list and then limit access to each folder based on the department. Or if that's not what you're looking for you honestly might be best creating separate lists for each department.

as George Norberg mentioned your can create Audiences per view.

Also you may want to stay away from Managed Navigation as that has a huge performance hit in page load times.